# Class Inherits Its Generic In Swift

Tags: swift, generics

In C++, I can implement it like this.

```
template<typename MyType>
class MyClass : public MyType
{    
};
```

Is it possible to do so in Swift?

```
///Compiler error: Inheritance from non-procotol, non-class type 'T'
class MyClass<MyGeneric> : MyGeneric
{
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't possible. Why do you want this exactly?

Comment: don't you mean `class MyClass<T: MyGeneric> : MyGeneric { }`...? because your syntax makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your class as a constraint.  The way you wrote it makes MyGeneric a placeholder name (and not a reference to the class with the same name):

```
class MyClass<T:MyGenericClass>:MyGenericClass
{}
```

This is assuming that what you're trying to get is something like this:

```
class MyGenericSubClass: MyGenericClass {}

let c = MyClass<MyGenericSubClass>()
```